# What is a "segregating gene"?

Tags: population-genetics

What does the term "segregating" mean in references like the following:

"found 42% of a random sample of loci to be segregating"
"15 blood group systems are known to be segregating"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, at a locus, you have several alleles, then this locus is said to be polymorphic or segregating.

A segregating locus is just an untintuitve name for a polymorphic locus.

Comment: But on a locus that is "segregating" what would be the "segregating allele"? Is it the one that is the "mutated allele" or the one that differ from the reference genome? Basically, how to know which one of the multiple alleles is the one "that segregates"?

Comment: I would assume that a "segregating allele" would be any allele at a segregating locus. My general feeling is that in a context this kind of expression quickly become very clear.

Comment: So in this case: "The segregating alleles that account for genetic variation in height may be the same in females and males, but in females they act in the context of a developmental plan that results in a smaller adult height." does that mean that polymorphic alleles (or the alleles that make the site polymorphic) account for genetic variation? Basically, is it possible to have segregating alleles that do not account for genetic variation? The quote is from Hartl, D. L., and A. G. Clark. 2007. Principles of population genetics. 4th ed. Sinauer P.419